# Do Bindings have to be observable collections, and why doesn't this work?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

In most tutorials I have seen for Data binding in Silverlight application for Windows Phone 7 the author uses and observable collection. Seen as my data isn't going to change after the time I bind it, is this entirely necessary? Why can't I just use a list?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach? :)

Also, Why does the following code not work? It looks like it should to me.

C# Contributor Class

```
    public class Contributor
    {
          public string Name;
          public string RSSUrl;

          public Contributor(string name, string rssURL)
          {
                  Name = name;
                  RSSUrl = rssURL;
          }
    }
```

C# Item Binding

```
            List<Contributor> people = new List<Contributor> { new Contributor("Danny", "www.dannybrown.com") };
        contributorsListBox.ItemsSource = people;
```

XAML

```
<!--Panorama item two-->
        <!--Use 'Orientation="Horizontal"' to enable a panel that lays out horizontally-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="contributors">
            <!--Double line list with image placeholder and text wrapping-->
            <ListBox x:Name="contributorsListBox" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                            <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FFE5001b" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
                            <StackPanel Width="311">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RSSUrl}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

As you can see, each Item has a red rectangle associated with it. I'm convinced the binding is sort of working because the correct amount of red rectangles appear whenever I change the amount of contributors in the list.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Danny.

Answer (score 3):

Your Contributor class needs to have properties, not just public fields.

```
public class Contributor
{
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string RSSUrl { get; set; }

      public Contributor(string name, string rssURL)
      {
              Name = name;
              RSSUrl = rssURL;
      }
}
```

Edit: With regards to your question, ObservableCollections are only needed where your data is going to change (i.e. you are adding or removing records). You can indeed bind to Lists or IEnumerables.

Comment: That was an easy fix. Its amazing how often I cannot see whats in front of my eyes. Thanks :)